# set_real_ip_from still included in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure my reverse nginx proxy to send the real IP address of the client instead of the proxy itself.

I am trying to implement as suggested in many posts I see but its not working as expected.

below is the relevant part of the `nginx.conf`

```
http {
  set_real_ip_from 123.0.0.0/8;
  set_real_ip_from 123.123.12.22; -- example ip
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive on;

  server {
    location @app {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    }


}
```

from what i understand the ip we set in `set_real_ip_from` are trusted ips and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will point to the first or last non trusted ips. But thats not happening.

When i try to print `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` is still see `123.123.12.22` and `request.remote_ip` still points to the proxy address `123.123.12.22`

Any help in this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is `123.123.12.22` an address of the client or is it another web server which redirects to this one and sets `X-Forwarded-For` to the real client IP?

Comment: the example ip `123.123.12.22` i have used is the proxy server ip, this is the IP, I am getting in my rails application and not the client IP

Answer (score 0):

Seems you misunderstand this nginx feature. `real_ip` module is for *restore* client address hidden to some additional header by another (front-end or load-balancing) web server.

You should remove all `real_ip` lines from nginx config and use `X-Real-IP` header in your application. If this isn't sufficient you can replace `X-Forwarded-For` in the server block with

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Hi @Lyzard Kyng, If i just use the `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` i am not getting the client ip, looks like its the nginx proxy ip still

Comment: @opensource-developer can you show me the hash `request.env.select { |key, value| key.match(/HTTP|REMOTE/) }` from your controller?